# How do you find a co-ordinates of a given perpendicular from point (x1 , y1)

Tags: c++, geometry

I have a polygon which can be regular as well as irregular one. I have to  do offsetting/buffering of polygon. I need to stretch the polygon by some amount of offset. The shape should be maintained.

Comment: 'stretch' as in .. enlarge on one direction (horizontally or vertically) ?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write for code for you.

Comment: Is there a stackoverflow for math? It could be called divisionbyzero.com or 1plus1equals2.com. :)

Comment: reword your question. most readers probably don't know what you are talking about and what problem you want solved

Answer (score 1):

The problem has several different solutions depending on your requirements.

A good place to start is to read the related section in the right column of this page.
Two good ones are:

1. [An algorithm for inflating/deflating (offsetting, buffering) polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons)
2. [How do you find a point a given perpendicular distance from a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133897/how-do-you-find-a-point-a-given-perpendicular-distance-from-a-line)

Will these two questions (with good answers) help you?
If not, please edit your question with more information about your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

multiply each coordinate whit offset

I knew, that somebody will not believe.
Ok here is full source in python (I used pythonxy )

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1, y1 = np.random.rand(2, 20)
plt.plot(x1,y1)

x2=x1*1.3
y2=y1*1.3

l=len(x1)

#calculate centers
cx1=sum(x1)/l
cy1=sum(y1)/l
cx2=sum(x2)/l
cy2=sum(y2)/l

#recenter polygon
x2=x2-(cx2-cx1)
y2=y2-(cy2-cy1)

plt.plot(x2,y2)
plt.show()
```

I made example whit random line but it is not different from your example

http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/8615/grafm.png

The reason that this works is because multiplying each point is same as stretching axes.
I calculated center as "average" and move one center over another, that way position looks more natural

Comment: This will only scale the polygon. It works for a regular polygon (box, pentagon, hexagon etc) with the origin in the center.