# calculate a perpendicular offset from a diagonal line

Tags: math, geometry, 2d, line, point

I am writing a music display program and need to draw a 'slur' between two notes.
A slur is a curved line linking two notes - just to be clear.

[image]

I know the note positions and calculate where the start and end points of the curve should be - Start point **A** and End point **B**.

I now need to obtain the offset **C**, given the distance required, for use within a quadratic curve.
This is where my, very, limited knowledge and understanding of maths formulae comes in.

I have indeed looked here in SO for my answer, but the solutions proposed either do not work or I am too limited to code them correctly.

Can someone help me with the calculation, in a **NON mathematical form** ?

Comment: Does the exact height of the parabola make a difference?

Comment: You want a parabolic curve that connects through A,B and has a peak on C? What is the height of C?

Comment: @PandaBearSoup - the height of the parabola will be variable depending on the distance between the notes - they are not necessarily adjacent.

Comment: Related: [Compute N different points lying on a line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31313903/183120).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Given the line segment AB, you can find the midpoint, say **M**, using the famous midpoint formula `(A + B)/2`. Now calculate the vector from **B** to **A**:

**p** = <p.x, p.y> = **A** ‒ **B**

[Rotate it about the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/346672/51968) by 90° counter-clockwise to get the perpendicular vector

**n** = <n.x, n.y> = < ‒ p.y, p.x >

Normalise it:

**n** = <n.x, n.y> / ‖n‖ where ‖n‖ = √(n.x² + n.y²) is the Euclidean Norm or length

**C** = L(t) = **M** + t **n**

Using this equation -- parametric form of a line -- you can find any number of points along the perpendicular line (in the direction of **n**). `t` is the distance of the obtained point, **C**, from **M**. When `t = 0`, you get **M** back, when `t = 1`, you get a point 1 unit away from **M** along **n** and so on. This also works for negative values of `t`, where the points obtained will be on the opposite side of AB i.e. towards the note. Since `t` can be a decimal number, you can play with it by changing its values to get the desired distance and direction of the obtained point from **M**.

Code, since you said you're not interested in the math jargon ;)

```
vec2d calculate_perp_point(vec2d A, vec2d B, float distance)
{
   vec2d M = (A + B) / 2;
   vec2d p = A - B;
   vec2d n = (-p.y, p.x);
   int norm_length = sqrt((n.x * n.x) + (n.y * n.y));
   n.x /= norm_length;
   n.y /= norm_length;
   return (M + (distance * n));
}
```

This is just pseudo code, since I'm not sure of the vector math library you are using for your project.

*Boldface variables above are 2-d vectors; uppercase letters denote points and lowercase ones are vectors with no position*

Comment: Thankyou for your time @legends2k.  If I have understood correctly, each operation done on your vec2d object applies to the x and y values equally ?

Comment: @Simon: Yes, when you see `p = B - A`, what it really means is `(p.x, p.y) = (B.x - A.x, B.y - A.y)` and the operation of a scalar and a vector like `distance * n` is really `(distance * n.x, distance * n.y)`. Happy to help :)

Comment: @Simon: If it'd helped you, I wouldn't mind if you accept the answer :)

Comment: thank you.  I've been testing after having to restart my system.

Comment: one further question, can you tell me how I could adapt this so as to have two control points for a cubic bezier ?  Should I open another question ?

Comment: @Simon Not required. `C = L(t) = M + t n` is nothing but a point M is pushed by the vector `n` which is `t` units long. So instead of M you can use any point along the line to push it to the required distance.

Comment: @Simon: So `C1` can be `M1 + t n` and `C2` can be `M2 + t n`; instead of `M = (A + B) / 2` which is halfway between A and B, M1 and M2 may be quarter and three-quarters between A and B i.e. `M1 = .75 B + .25 A` and `M2 = .25B + .75A`. In general any point along A and B can be obtained using the formula `M = (1 - t) B + tA` where t is the distance from B.

Comment: @Simon: I've changed the calculation of p from `B - A` to `A - B` which is appropriate since a vector from B to A would be given by the latter and not the former.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32091/discussion-between-simon-and-legends2k)

Answer (score 3):

I took legends2k excellent answer and converted to Java on Android.  This might help someone save some time.

```
private PointF getPerpendicularPoint(int startX, int startY, int stopX, int stopY, float distance)
{
    PointF M = new PointF((startX + stopX) / 2, (startY + stopY) / 2);
    PointF p = new PointF(startX - stopX, startY - stopY);
    PointF n = new PointF(-p.y, p.x);
    int norm_length = (int) Math.sqrt((n.x * n.x) + (n.y * n.y));
    n.x /= norm_length;
    n.y /= norm_length;
    return new PointF(M.x + (distance * n.x), M.y + (distance * n.y));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And here’s a Swift version:

```
func pointNormalToLine(startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint, distance: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {

    let midpoint = CGPoint(x: (startPoint.x + endPoint.x) / 2, y: (startPoint.y + endPoint.y) / 2)
    let p = CGPoint(x: startPoint.x - endPoint.x, y: startPoint.y - endPoint.y)
    var n = CGPoint(x: -p.y, y: p.x)
    let norm_length = sqrt((n.x * n.x) + (n.y * n.y))
    n.x /= norm_length
    n.y /= norm_length
    return CGPoint(x: midpoint.x + (distance * n.x), y: midpoint.y + (distance * n.y))
}
```