# Given two points (x1,y1) (x2,y2), how can I compute N different points evenly lying on the line between the given points

Tags: c++, math, geometry, line, point

I have two points and I would like to compute n evenly distributed points on top of the line created by the given line. How could I perform this in c++?

Comment: Should these points be uniformely distributed along the segment ?

Comment: Yes uniformly. I am also working on this. If I run the code will post it.

Comment: Repeatedly, X+= DX, Y+= DY, where DX=(X2-X1)/N, DY=(Y2-Y1)/N.

Comment: Good question. If something non-uniform is needed, look at non-linear interpolations like hermite, cosine, smoothstep, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) (affectionately called *lerp* by the Graphics community) is what you want. Given the end points it can generate the points lying in between with a parameter `t`.

Let the end points be `A (Ax, Ay)` and `B (Bx, By)`. The vector spanning from `A` to `B` would be given by

```
V = B − A = <Vx, Vy>
L(t) = A + tV
```

This essentially means that starting from the point `A`, we scale the vector `V` with the scalar `t`; the point `A` is displaced by this scaled vector and thus the point we get depends on the value of `t`, the parameter. When `t = 0`, we get back `A`, if `t = 1` we get `B`, if it's `0.5` we get the point midway between `A` and `B`.

```
line A----|----|----|----B
   t 0    ¼    ½    ¾    1
```

It works for any line (slope doesn't matter). Now coming to your problem of `N` stops. If you need `N` to be 10, then you'd have `t` vary by `1/N`, so `t = i/10`, where `i` would be the loop iterator.

```
i = 0, t = 0
i = 1, t = 0.1
i = 2, t = 0.2
  ⋮
i = 9, t = 0.9
i = 10, t = 1.0
```

Here's one way to implement it:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
    float x, y;
};

Point operator+ (Point const &pt1, Point const &pt2) {
    return { pt1.x + pt2.x, pt1.y + pt2.y };
}

Point operator- (Point const &pt1, Point const &pt2) {
    return { pt1.x - pt2.x, pt1.y - pt2.y };
}

Point scale(Point const &pt, float t) {
    return { pt.x * t, pt.y * t };
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Point const &pt) {
    return os << '(' << pt.x << ", " << pt.y << ')';
}

void lerp(Point const &pt1, Point const &pt2, float stops) {
    Point const v = pt2 - pt1;
    float t = 0.0f;
    for (float i = 0.0f; i <= stops; ++i) {
        t = i / stops;
        Point const p = pt1 + scale(v, t);
        std::cout << p << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    lerp({0.0, 0.0}, {5.0f, 5.0f}, 5.0f);
}
```

#### Output

```
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
(5, 5)
```

#### Aside

Notice that on every iteration `t` gets incremented by `Δt = 1 / N`. Thus another way to update `t` in a loop would be

```
t₀ = 0
t₁ = t₀ + Δt
t₂ = t₁ + Δt
  ⋮
t₉ = t₈ + Δt
t₁₀ = t₉ + Δt
```

However, this isn't very parallelizable since every iteration of the loop would depend on the previous iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `give_uniform_points_between(M, N, num_points)` which gives a number of `#num_points` points between `M` and `N`. I assume here that the line is not vertical (see below if the line can be vertical).

```
std::vector<Point> give_uniform_points_between(const Point& M, const Point& N, const unsigned num_points) {
   std::vector<Point> result;
   // get equation y = ax + b
    float a = (N.y - M.y) / (N.x - M.x);
    float b = N.y - a * N.x;
    float step = std::fabs(M.x - N.x) / num_points;
    for (float x = std::min(M.x, N.x); x < std::max(M.x, N.x); x += step) {
        float y = a*x+b;
        result.push_back(Point{x,y});
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Demo : <kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25fa59bfc13ec22c)</kbd>**

and result is :

> (-3,9);(-2.3,7.6);(-1.6,6.2);(-0.9,4.8);(-0.2,3.4);(0.5,2);(1.2,0.6);(1.9,-0.8);(2.6,-2.2);(3.3,-3.6);

**Explanation**

From two points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` you can guess the line equation which pass through these points.

This equation takes the form `a*x + b*y + c = 0` or simply `y = a*x + b` if you cannot have vertical line 
where `a = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)` and you deduce b as shown in the code.

Then you can just vary `x` or `y` along your line starting for the point with a minimum value coordinate.

All these `(x,y)` points you find are on your line and should be uniformely distributed (thanks to the fixed `step`).

Comment: Perhaps it is quite simple when you do some maths, but you don't seem to have shown the maths, eg how to calculate a, b and c, or min, max and step. You divide by b, but there is nothing to prevent b being zero! "guess the line equation"? Guessing line equations is not likely to have a high success rate!

Comment: I show how to calculate a, b, c, min and max. I ll edit to precise for step it's really simple to do that... And I divide by b assuming it's not a vertical line...

Answer (score 1):

View the line as (x1,y1) + λ(x2-x1,y2-y1), i.e. the first point, plus a multiple of the vector between them.

When λ=0 you have the first point and when λ=1 you have the second.
So you just want to take n equally distributed values of λ between 0 and 1.

How you do this depends on what you mean by between: are the end points included or not?

For example you could take λ=0/(n-1), λ=1/(n-1), λ=2/(n-1), ... λ=(n-1)/(n-1).
That would give n equally distributed points including the endpoints.

Or you could take λ=1/(n+1), λ=2/(n+1), ... λ=n/(n+1).
That would give n equally distributed points not including the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Not so mcuh math though...

```
vector<Rect> Utils::createReactsOnLine(Point pt1, Point pt2, int numRects, int height, int width){

    float x1 = pt1.x;
    float y1 = pt1.y;
    float x2 = pt2.x;
    float y2 = pt2.y;

    float x_range = std::abs(x2 - x1);
    float y_range = std::abs(y2 - y1);

    // Find center points of rects on the line
    float x_step_size = x_range / (float)(numRects-1);
    float y_step_size = y_range / (float)(numRects-1);

    float x_min = std::min(x1,x2);
    float y_min = std::min(x1,x2);
    float x_max = std::max(x1,x2);
    float y_max = std::max(x1,x2);

    cout << numRects <<  endl;
    float next_x = x1;
    float next_y = y1;
    cout << "Next x, y: "<< next_x << "," <<  next_y <<  endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < numRects-1; i++){
        if (x1 < x2)
            next_x = next_x + x_step_size;
        else
            next_x = next_x - x_step_size;

        if (y1 < y2)
            next_y = next_y + y_step_size;
        else
            next_y = next_y - y_step_size;

        cout << "Next x, y: "<< next_x << "," <<  next_y <<  endl;
    }
    return vector<Rect>();
}
```