# Find 2 point with same distance from A

Tags: geometry, distance

I have a math problem. I have location (x,y) of point A, B, and a number (x). I want to calculate the location of point C, D. CD is perpendicular with AB and AC = AD = x.

This is the picture describe my problem:

[image: my problem]

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is not a right place to post this question.....

Comment: You have a math problem, this is a site for helping people with programming problems.

Comment: Hey your question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133897/how-do-you-find-a-point-at-a-given-perpendicular-distance-from-a-line .Refer this question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark then why are the tags geometry and distance on SO?

Comment: I did not see the possible duplicate before posting my answer, but interestingly that question (and the answer) got a lot of upvotes and no closing votes ...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark sorry because I develop for iphone so I post my question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify a programming language, but from your previous questions it seems that
you have some experience with (Objective-)C and Core Graphics on iOS, so this would be
a solution using C and Core Graphics data structures:

```
// Your input data:
CGPoint A = ...
CGPoint B = ...
CGFloat x = ...

// Vector from A to B:
CGPoint vecAB = CGPointMake(B.x - A.x, B.y - A.y);
// Length of that vector:
CGFloat lenAB = hypotf(vecAB.x, vecAB.y);
// Perpendicular vector, normalized to length 1:
CGPoint perp = CGPointMake(-vecAB.y/lenAB, vecAB.x/lenAB);

CGPoint C = CGPointMake(A.x + x * perp.x, A.y + x * perp.y);
CGPoint D = CGPointMake(A.x - x * perp.x, A.y - x * perp.y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to [How do you find a point at a given perpendicular distance from a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133897/how-do-you-find-a-point-at-a-given-perpendicular-distance-from-a-line) . If you want further mathemetical details, you can refer: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html