# How to find a point in 3-D at an arbitrary perpendicular line given distance to the point

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, geometry, language-agnostic

I have a line AB. I would like to draw a line BC, perpendicular to AB. I know xyz of the points A and B, I also know the distance N between B and C. How can I find an arbitrary point C which fits into the given parameters? The calculations should be done in 3-D. Any point, perpendicular to AB can be the point C, if its distance to B equals N.

An almost identical question is given here, but I would like to know how the same thing is done in 3-D: [How do you find a point at a given perpendicular distance from a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133897/how-do-you-find-a-point-at-a-given-perpendicular-distance-from-a-line)

The calculation that works for me in 2-D was given in the link above:

```
dx = A.x-B.x
dy = A.y-B.y
dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
dx /= dist
dy /= dist
C.x = B.x + N*dy
C.y = B.y - N*dx
```

I tried adding Z axis to it like this:

```
dz = A.z - B.z 
dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz) 
dz /=dist 
C.z = .... at this point it becomes a mystery to me
```

If I put something like "C.z - N*dz" into C.z, the distance is accurate only in some rotation angles, I would like to know the correct solution. I can imagine that in 3-D it is calculated in a completely different manner.

**Clarification**

- Point C is not unique. It can be any point on a *circle* with its
  centre at B and radius N. The *circle* is perpendicular to AB

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the point `C` that has distance `N` from `B` is not unique. It is actually all the points on a *circle* that with `B` as a center and `N` as radius.

Comment: @Aziz, yes, you are correct. Point C can be any point on that circle.

Comment: Do you know enough about 3D vectors to implement the vector algorithm I just gave in my answer?

Comment: @Rory, thank you very much for you answer. It would be helpful if you could show how it's done in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the desired point C can be any of the infinitely-many points fitting your requirements, here is one method.

Choose any vector that is not parallel or anti-parallel to vector AB. You could try the vector `(1, 0, 0)`, and if that is parallel you could use `(0, 1, 0)` instead. Then take the cross-product of vector AB and the chosen vector. That cross-product is perpendicular to vector AB. Divide that cross-product by its length then multiply by the desired length N. Finally extend that vector from point B to find your desired point C.

Here is code in Python 3 that follows that algorithm. This code is somewhat non-pythonic to make it easier to convert to other languages. (If I really did this for myself I would use the `numpy` module to avoid coordinates completely and shorten this code.) But it does treat the points as tuples of 3 values: many languages will require you to handle each coordinate separately. Any real-life code would need to check for "near zero" rather than "zero" and to check that the `sqrt` calculation does not result in zero. I'll leave those additional steps to you. Ask if you have more questions.

```
from math import sqrt

def pt_at_given_distance_from_line_segment_and_endpoint(a, b, dist):
    """Return a point c such that line segment bc is perpendicular to
    line segment ab and segment bc has length dist.

    a and b are tuples of length 3, dist is a positive float.
    """
    vec_ab = (b[0]-a[0], b[1]-a[1], b[2]-a[2])
    # Find a vector not parallel or antiparallel to vector ab
    if vec_ab[1] != 0 or vec_ab[2] != 0:
        vec = (1, 0, 0)
    else:
        vec = (0, 1, 0)
    # Find the cross product of the vectors
    cross = (vec_ab[1] * vec[2] - vec_ab[2] * vec[1],
             vec_ab[2] * vec[0] - vec_ab[0] * vec[2],
             vec_ab[0] * vec[1] - vec_ab[1] * vec[0])
    # Find the vector in the same direction with length dist
    factor = dist / sqrt(cross[0]**2 + cross[1]**2 + cross[2]**2)
    newvec = (factor * cross[0], factor * cross[1], factor * cross[2])
    # Find point c such that vector bc is that vector
    c = (b[0] + newvec[0], b[1] + newvec[1], b[2] + newvec[2])
    # Done!
    return c
```

The resulting output from the command

```
print(pt_at_given_distance_from_line_segment_and_endpoint((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), 2))
```

is

```
(4.0, 6.414213562373095, 4.585786437626905)
```

Comment: It was my first question, and I am delighted to get such a quick and wonderful answer!